# Problem with TikZ, beamer and verbatim

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, verbatim

I'm trying to put verbatim text inside a node (in a beamer frame):

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{P}
\tikzstyle{cell} = [rectangle, draw, thin , fill=black!10 , minimum size=5mm]
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm, auto,>=latex', thick, overlay]
    \path[->,draw]<1-> node[cell] (p) {Text at \verb!p!};                
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

But it doesn't compile and produces an error. If one replaces `\verb!p!` with anything else, like "`p`", it compiles. Note that I also tried to put
"`fragile`" in the frame options. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I can't test right now: Does the problem persist when you do the same thing (verbatim in a node) in a "normal" (i.e. `article`) document class?

Comment: Do you need verbatim, or can you just write `\texttt{p}`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `\Verb` from the [fancyvrb](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{P}
\tikzstyle{cell} = [rectangle, draw, thin , fill=black!10 , minimum size=5mm]
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm, auto,>=latex', thick, overlay]
    \path[->,draw] node[cell] (p) {Text at \Verb!p!};                
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As **Caramdir** has correctly suspected in a comment, if another document class (`article`, for example) is used there's no need to use `\Verb` and the standard `\verb` command will work.

[image]

You should also consider using `\texttt{p}` instead of `\verb!p!` (as  **Torbjørn T** suggested in his comment) if your intention is just to use a mono-spaced font for the "p" character.

Comment: You forgot the `<1->` from the OP. (although it's probably no-op here, it's responsible for the broken behavior of verb. Without `<1->`, it works both with and without `Verb`. // Side note, read the documentation of `fancyvrb` for remark on how to use `Verb`, it's different (e.g. you need to escape spaces etc.) Could just use `\texttt{` for simplicity.