# Verbatim inside tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, verbatim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with TikZ, beamer and verbatim](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50525/problem-with-tikz-beamer-and-verbatim)

Is it possible to use `verbatim`-like environments inside a `tikz` node? This MWE gives an error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikz{
  \node{\begin{verbatim}a_b\end{verbatim}};
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I saw that, but the answer notes 'if another document class (article, for example) ...' -- so that looks beamer-specific, no?

Comment: Do you really need `\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}`?

Comment: I need an environment constructed for me in other answers that is like `verbatim`...

Comment: Actually the correct duplicate is [Verbatim in tikz node - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345871/verbatim-in-tikz-node/652131#652131).

Answer (score 7):

I get `missing item` error with your MWE. However, it seems to work with `listings` package. If you would allow it, then try the code below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\begin{document}

\tikz
\node at (0,0) {
\begin{lstlisting}
a_b
\end{lstlisting}
};

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This other command works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] at (0,0) {\verb+a_b+};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```