# Verbatim in tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am trying to have a verbatim environment in a tikz node just next to some other nodes.

I have tried

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (s1) {$a$};
\node (s2) [right=of s1] {$b$};
\node (s3) [above right=0cm and 1cm of s2] {$c$};
\node (s4) [below right=0cm and 1cm of s2] {$d$};

\node[right=6cm of s2] {%

   verbatim environment

};

\path (s1) edge (s2);
\path (s2) edge (s3);
\path (s2) edge (s4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

but if I add `\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}`, it does not work any longer.

What I want is to have some nodes on the left and the some text in verbatim style on the right and a arrow from the nodes on the left to the text on the right.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way is to save one or more `verbbox`es prior to entering the `tikz`.  Then, recall them as needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,verbatimbox}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{myverbbox}{\sTWO}
This i$ my \verbatim
  environment
\\##@
\end{myverbbox}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (s1) {$a$};
\node (s2) [right=of s1] {$b$};
\node (s3) [above right=0cm and 1cm of s2] {$c$};
\node (s4) [below right=0cm and 1cm of s2] {$d$};

\node[right=6cm of s2] {\sTWO};

\path (s1) edge (s2);
\path (s2) edge (s3);
\path (s2) edge (s4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a version that demonstrates multiple `verbbox`es, the second one in color and `\footnotesize`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,verbatimbox}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{myverbbox}{\sTWO}
This i$ my \verbatim
  environment
\\##@
\end{myverbbox}
{\color{red}
\begin{myverbbox}[\footnotesize]{\sTWELVE}
Another
 verbatim &$#^_ environment
\end{myverbbox}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (s1) {$a$};
\node (s2) [right=of s1] {$b$};
\node (s3) [above right=0cm and 1cm of s2] {$c$};
\node (s4) [below right=0cm and 1cm of s2] {$d$};

\node[right=6cm of s2] {\sTWO};

\path (s1) edge (s2);
\path (s2) edge (s3);
\path (s2) edge (s4);

\node (s11) [below=2cm of s1] {$e$};
\node (s12) [right=of s11] {$f$};
\node (s13) [above right=0cm and 1cm of s12] {$g$};
\node (s14) [below right=0cm and 1cm of s12] {$h$};

\node[right=6cm of s12] {\sTWELVE};

\path (s11) edge (s12);
\path (s12) edge (s13);
\path (s12) edge (s14);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You don't really need the verbatim text inside a node at all. If you take it out of the `tikzpicture`, you can just put it into a `minipage` or something to align it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
  \node (s1) {$a$};
  \node (s2) [right=of s1] {$b$};
  \node (s3) [above right=0cm and 1cm of s2] {$c$};
  \node (s4) [below right=0cm and 1cm of s2] {$d$};
  \draw (s1) -- (s2) edge (s3) -- (s4);
  \path [->] (s2 -| s4.east) edge ++(10mm,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.5\linewidth}
\begin{verbatim}
  Some verbatim stuff
  in a
  minipage
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: verbatim alongside diagram]

Comment: I wish the down-voter would say *why*!

Comment: (not the downvoter, just coming across this answer many years later, but it could be because in other cases it's necessary to place the verbatim text between the nodes so this answer is not as useful in that case...)

Answer (score 3):

While TikZ nodes support `\verb` in the node text they don't support the `verbatim` environment (for reasons I am not completely clear on).

But just for fun, how about rolling your own verbatim environment?

Here's a minimal-ish implementation which can automatically determine the line width (using the `auto` option). Alternatively the `text width` option to the node can be given which will wrap long lines. Otherwise you get one long line.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\makeatletter
\def\makeother#1{\catcode`#1=12\relax}
\def\makeactive#1{\catcode`#1=13\relax}
{
\catcode`\|=\catcode`\\
\catcode`\[=\catcode`\{
\catcode`\]=\catcode`\}
|makeother\\
|makeother|{
|makeother|}
|makeactive|^^M%
|long|gdef|docollect#1^^M\end{vrbtm}[|aftercollect[#1]]%
]
{
\makeactive\ %
\gdef\dospace{\makeactive\ \def {\spaceaction}}
}
{
\makeactive\^^M%
\gdef\doreturn{\makeactive\^^M\def^^M{\returnaction}}%
\gdef\beforecollect{\@ifnextchar^^M{\afterassignment\docollect\let\token=}%
  {\docollect}}%
}

\def\spaceaction{\hskip1ex}
\def\returnaction{\par\leavevmode}

\newbox\vrbbxa
\newbox\vrbbxb

\def\autobeforetypeset{%
  \let\returnaction=\autoline%
  \setbox\vrbbxa=\hbox\bgroup\ignorespaces}

\def\autoline{%
    \unskip%
  \egroup%
  \autoaddtobox%
  \setbox\vrbbxa=\hbox\bgroup\ignorespaces}

\def\autoaddtobox{%
  \ifdim\wd\vrbbxb<\wd\vrbbxa%
    \let\tmpbx=\vrbbxa%
  \else%
    \let\tmpbx=\vrbbxb%
  \fi%
  \setbox\vrbbxb=\vbox{\hsize=\wd\tmpbx%
    \ifvoid\vrbbxb\else\box\vrbbxb\fi\box\vrbbxa}%
}

\def\autoaftertypeset{%
   \unskip%
  \egroup%
  \autoaddtobox%
  \box\vrbbxb%
}

\def\beforetypeset{\noindent}
\long\def\typeset#1{#1}
\def\aftertypeset{\unskip}

\pgfkeys{vrbtm/.cd,
  auto/.code={%
    \let\beforetypeset=\autobeforetypeset
    \let\aftertypeset=\autoaftertypeset
  }
}
\def\vrbtm{\@ifnextchar[\vrbtmopts{\vrbtmopts[]}}
\def\vrbtmopts[#1]{%
  \begingroup%
    \pgfkeys{vrbtm/.cd,#1}%
    \let\do=\makeother%
    \dospecials%
    \dospace%
    \doreturn%
    \beforecollect}

\def\aftercollect#1{%
  \beforetypeset%
  \typeset{#1}%
  \aftertypeset%
  \endgroup%
  \end{vrbtm}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\ttfamily}]

\node[draw] (A) {%
\begin{vrbtm}[auto]
Here i$  $ome 
 verb&tim_text

with 
{automat~c} \line lengt# c%lcul%tion
\end{vrbtm}
};

\node[draw, below=of A, text width=4cm] (B) {%
\begin{vrbtm}
Here i$  $ome 
 verb&tim_text

with 
{te#t width} and word wrap
\end{vrbtm}
};

\node[draw, below=of B] (C) {%
\begin{vrbtm}
Here i$ $ome 
 verb&tim_text

 without
 {anything} \cle^er
\end{vrbtm}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In 99% of the cases, if you can't use verbatim-like things inside something-else it's because of catcode problems.

In this case however, you'd guess that it's not the case because `\verb` works well.

Instead, **the actual reason is that `verbatim` environment doesn't work in restricted horizontal mode (that is, the mode inside a `\hbox`).**

As such, any solutions in [Manual/automatic line breaks and text alignment in TikZ nodes - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123671/manual-automatic-line-breaks-and-text-alignment-in-tikz-nodes) would work (as long as they don't, in addition, mess with the catcode)

For example, using `text width` attribute:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (s1) {$a$};
\node (s2) [right=of s1] {$b$};
\node (s3) [above right=0cm and 1cm of s2] {$c$};
\node (s4) [below right=0cm and 1cm of s2] {$d$};

\node[right=6cm of s2, text width=4cm] {%

\begin{verbatim}
verbatim environment
\end{verbatim}

};

\path (s1) edge (s2);
\path (s2) edge (s3);
\path (s2) edge (s4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

There's an overfull hbox though. (6cm is too much)

Similarly, `{minipage}` environment works.

The solution using `tabular` doesn't work however (technical details, `tabular` uses the `\halign` primitive, which typesets the content inside each cell in restricted horizontal mode).

Comment: The same applies for displaymath environments from `amsmath` (e.g. `align` and variants). They just need a `text width`, a `minipage` or …