# Embedding code snippet in a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, code

I was trying to modify a latex snippet that gave this output:

[image]

so that a small C code snippet is place above the 'Code A' and 'Code B' labels as in

```
                right
   +--------------->-------------+
   |                             |
   |                             |
main {                        int main {              
  printf("Hello\n");            printf("Hello\n");
}                               return 0;                   
                              }

Code A                        Code B
   |                             |
   |                             |
   +---------------<-------------+
                left
```

So I tried to do

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,chains,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=2cm,
  font=\small,
  block/.style = {align=center}
]
\node (codeA) [block] {
%    \begin{verbatim}
%    main {
%       printf("Hello\n");
%    }
%    \end{verbatim}
    \tiny{Code A}
};

\node (codeB) [block, right=of codeA] {
%    \begin{verbatim}
%    int main {
%       printf("Hello\n");
%       return 0;
%    }
%    \end{verbatim}
    \tiny{Code B}
};

\path [-latex]
  (codeA.north) edge [bend left=35]
    node[above] {right} (codeB.north);
\path [-latex]  (codeB.south) edge [bend left=35]
    node[below] {left} (codeA.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But using an environment in the label part gave error.

How can this be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/345871/110998

Comment: Not exactly. There the verbatim env seems to be outside the tikzpicture. Not sure if that can be adopted for my use case though..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple fix is to place the verbatim environment inside a minipage

Also, `\tiny` command doesn't take as argument the text that you want to scale but no argument at all... See the changed command.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,chains,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=2cm,
  font=\small,
  block/.style = {align=center}
]
\node (codeA) [block] {%
\centering
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
\centering
    \begin{verbatim}
    main {
       printf("Hello\n");
    }
    \end{verbatim}

    {\tiny Code A}
\end{minipage}%
};

\node (codeB) [block, right=of codeA] {%
\centering
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
\centering
    \begin{verbatim}
    int main {
       printf("Hello\n");
       return 0;
    }
    \end{verbatim}

    {\tiny Code B}
\end{minipage}%
};

\path [-latex]
  (codeA.north) edge [bend left=35]
    node[above] {right} (codeB.north);
\path [-latex]  (codeB.south) edge [bend left=35]
    node[below] {left} (codeA.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,chains,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=2cm,
  font=\small,
  block/.style = {align=center}
]
\node (codeA) [block] {%
\centering
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
\centering
    \begin{verbatim}
    main {
       printf("Hello\n");
    }
    \end{verbatim}
\vspace{3mm}

{\tiny Code A}%
\end{minipage}
};

\node (codeB) [block, right=of codeA] {%
\centering
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
\centering
    \begin{verbatim}
    int main {
       printf("Hello\n");
       return 0;
    }
    \end{verbatim}

\vspace{-2mm}

{\tiny Code B}%
\end{minipage}
};

\path [-latex]
  (codeA.north) edge [bend left=35]
    node[above] {right} (codeB.north);
\path [-latex]  (codeB.south) edge [bend left=35]
    node[below] {left} (codeA.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the `Code A` and `Code B` to appear on the same level as well? Horizontally.

Comment: Hadn't realized that `\tiny` works that way.

Comment: Try the edited code...

Comment: But now the codeA and codeB labels appear besides the code snippets and not below them. Is that possible?

Comment: Tried changing hskip to vskip and then to vspace but both didn't work..

Comment: add an empty line after your vskip (See edit)