# How do I align text that can be drawn over?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, vertical-alignment

I would like to take two lines of column-aligned text (double-stranded DNA data) and add some boxes around some of the text, and additional labels. I normally use tikz for this kind of figure, but I am having difficulties retaining the column-aligned text in tikz.

```
      ATTGGNAGCAGAACCCCATGCGCTGGCGCGGCTACGACAGCTAACTTGAGA...
...AGATAACNNTCGTCTTGGGGTACGCGACCGCGCCGATGCTNTCGATTGAAC
```

I have tried using a Verbatim (fancyvrb) and verbatim environment inside a tikz node, but this has compilation errors like [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86227/verbatim-inside-tikz-node?noredirect=1&lq=1).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Duplicates}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[align=left]{
        \begin{Verbatim}
      ATTGGNAGCAGAACCCCATGCGCTGGCGCGGCTACGACAGCTAACTTGAGA...
...AGATAACNNTCGTCTTGGGGTACGCGACCGCGCCGATGCTNTCGATTGAAC
        \end{Verbatim}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

> ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
>   l.4 \begin{Verbatim}

The question above is marked as a duplicate of a [question whose answer indicates to use `\Verb`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50525/problem-with-tikz-beamer-and-verbatim), which is not appropriate for my long strings.

I have also tried to use `\texttt` within a tikz node, but this does not align correctly.

```
\node[align=left]{
\texttt{      ATTGGNAGCAGAACCCCATGCGCTGGCGCGGCTACGACAGCTAACTTGAGA...}\\
\texttt{...AGATAACNNTCGTCTTGGGGTACGCGACCGCGCCGATGCTNTCGATTGAAC}
};
```

I have also considered using a tikz matrix, but this seems overly complicated with one node per letter.

Is there a relatively simple way of achieving the aligned text with drawing features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't help you with the `tikz` overlays, but getting verbatim into the `tikz` node can be done with `verbatimbox`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Duplicates}
\begin{verbbox}[\small]
      ATTGGNAGCAGAACCCCATGCGCTGGCGCGGCTACGACAGCTAACTTGAGA...
...AGATAACNNTCGTCTTGGGGTACGCGACCGCGCCGATGCTNTCGATTGAAC
\end{verbbox}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[align=left]{\theverbbox};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps a less efficient way to add bells and whistles, but one which I *do* know is a `\stackinset`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatimbox,stackengine,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Duplicates}
\begin{verbbox}[\small]
      ATTGGNAGCAGAACCCCATGCGCTGGCGCGGCTACGACAGCTAACTTGAGA...
...AGATAACNNTCGTCTTGGGGTACGCGACCGCGCCGATGCTNTCGATTGAAC
\end{verbbox}
\stackinset{l}{100pt}{c}{}{\textcolor{red}{\framebox(68,22){}}}{\theverbbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You also can put your text in a parbox and use one of the  `\seqsplit` or `\DNA` commands, from the `seqsplit` and `dnaseq` packages:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{dnaseq, seqsplit}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Duplicates}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[align=left
 ]{\parbox{\linewidth}
 {\ttfamily\seqsplit{ATTGGNAGCAGAACCCCATGCGCTGGCGCGGCTACGACAGCTAACTTGAGA...
...AGATAACNNTCGTCTTGGGGTACGCGACCGCGCCGATGCTNTCGATTGAAC}

\DNA! ATTGGNAGCAGAACCCCATGCGCTGGCGCGGCTACGACAGCTAACTTGAGA...
...AGATAACNNTCGTCTTGGGGTACGCGACCGCGCCGATGCTNTCGATTGAAC! }
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]